# Creating a short dynamic link using unity firebase throwing error

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm able to create long dynamic link without issues. Debug also not showing any issues. When I try to create short dynamic link using following code it is throwing error
`

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.ShortDynamicLink link = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.DynamicLinks.GetShortLinkAsync(components.LongDynamicLink,  options);
```

`

> FirebaseException: 400: Your project does not own Dynamic Links domain: https://example.page.link [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]

Firebase console contains this url link prefix and domain is verified.

I have tried changing url prefix but didn't help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was pointing specifically that creating short dynamic link using unity sdk 8.0.0 is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was with the firebase unity SDK(8.0.0) which I was using. When I tried creating short dynamic link with rest call using api_key it worked fine with same parameters which I was using in unity sdk.